# ¿Cómo refrescar un ListView con nuevos datos?

Tags: android, listview, spinner

Tengo el siguiente problema. Presento un ListView con datos (extraidos de una base de datos). Esto me funciona sin problemas.

Ahora bien, quiero que los datos del ListView se 'refresquen' al cambiar la fecha que tengo en un Spinner, es decir, que se borren los anteriores y se pongan los nuevos. Sin embargo, no consigo que esto funcione. De momento, lo máximo que he conseguido es que me ponga unos datos debajo de los anteriores.

Este es un resumen de mi código:

```
    Spinner spinFechas;
    ListView lista_preguntas;
    Button btnIrFechaSpinner;

    String fechaSpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cuestionarios_alumo);

            spinFechas = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerFechasEvalua);
            lista_preguntas = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewCuestiones);
            btnIrFechaSpinner = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonFechasSpinner);

    obt_fechas_cuestionarios();

            btnIrFechaSpinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    fechaSpinner = spinFechas.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    obt_ciclo_cursoEscolar();
                }
            });
    }


        public void obt_fechas_cuestionarios(){

            String url = "MY_URL";

            StringRequest eventfulRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {

                                String fecha;


                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                                for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                    fecha = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("fecha");

                                    Fechas.add(fecha);

                                }

                                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CuestionariosAlumoActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Fechas);
                                spinFechas.setAdapter(adapter);

                                fechaSpinner = spinFechas.getSelectedItem().toString();

                                obt_ciclo_cursoEscolar()


                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            //Log.e("Error: ", error.toString());
                        }
                    });

            VolleySingleton.getInstance(this)
                    .addToRequestQueue(eventfulRequest);
        }


    public void obt_ciclo_cursoEscolar(){

        String url = "MYURL2";

        StringRequest eventfulRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            String codigoCiclo;

                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                            for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                codigoCiclo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_ciclo");

                                CodigosCiclos.add(codigoCiclo);                                
                            }
CargaLista();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                            }
                });

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this)
                .addToRequestQueue(eventfulRequest);
    }


     public void CargaLista(){
            myadaptercuestiones myadaptercuestiones = new myadaptercuestiones(this, R.layout.list_item_cuestiones, CodigosCuestionarios, Preguntas, Observaciones);
    myadaptercuestiones.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lista_preguntas.setAdapter(myadaptercuestiones);
        }
```

Es decir, la actividad muestra un listview con datos y, al cambiar la fecha, debe mostrar otros diferentes. He probado con el notifyDataSetChanged(), pero sólo consigo que me acumule todos los datos, no que me borre unos y me muestros otros datos.

Gracias y un saludo!

Comment: En que momento deberia cambiar los datos? al selecciona del spinner o la presionar el boton?

Comment: Al presionar el botón. Aunque reconozco que lo he intentado de ambas maneras, pero no consigo dar con una solución.

Comment: entoces al presionar el boton debes ejecutar nuevamente el metodo que llena el listview, `CargaLista()`

Comment: Gracias por responder. Aunque me sigue haciendo lo mismo. Carga unos datos en el ListView, y al darle al botón, en lugar de limpiar y cargar, me acumula ambos datos.

Comment: entonces antes de ejecutar el metodo has `lista_preguntas.setAdapter(null);` para limpiar el listview

Comment: Necesitas inicializar las variables en 0, Yo tenia un problema como el tuyo, recuerda que volley primero consulta si hay cambios y si no los regresa para no estar haciendo peticiones, entonces necesitas declarar las variables en 0 o null arriba del for donde esta la funciona de mostrar los valores. Yo puse un calendario para cambiar fechas, y al momento de darle al boton aceptar mande a llamar otra vez la función de mostrar datos y nunca aplique el notifyDataSetChanged(), solo cuando quería borrar un elemento de la lista.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Efectivamente mi error estaba en que no limpiaba los Arrays al volver a llamar a la función. Tu respuesta me puso en el buen camino. Gracias mil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema esta en tus listas. Siempre estas agregando los items, es por eso que siempre se acumulan, lo que deberías hacer es primero limpiar tu lista y luego agregar los nuevos elementos.

Asumiendo que en la siguiente linea de código

```
myadaptercuestiones myadaptercuestiones = new myadaptercuestiones(this, R.layout.list_item_cuestiones, CodigosCuestionarios, Preguntas, Observaciones);
```

Los objetos CodigoCuestionarios, Preguntas y Observaciones son listas (ArrayList, List) puedes puedes llamar el método clear().

Comment: Esa es precisamente mi duda, cómo limpiar unos items antes de agregar otros. Pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Claro! Bueno asumiendo que en la siguiente linea de código
myadaptercuestiones myadaptercuestiones = new myadaptercuestiones(this, R.layout.list_item_cuestiones, CodigosCuestionarios, Preguntas, Observaciones);

Los objetos CodigoCuestionarios, Preguntas y Observaciones son listas (ArrayList, List) puedes puedes llamar el método clear().

Te comparto un ejemplo:


https://github.com/RaulitoGC/Technology-Store-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rguzman/techstore/presentation/product/ProductAdapter.java

Comment: Ostras! Pues sí. Justo ahí estaba mi fallo. No limpiaba los Arrays al volver a llamar al método que iba a la fecha seleccionado. Muchas gracias de verdad!!